# How can I write this symbol in LaTeX? Does it exist in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I would like to write this Greek symbol and I tried with `\boldsymbol{\chi}` but doesn't look the same. I appreciate an answer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It looks more  like a boldface calligraphic X than a Greek letter.

Comment: The font is very close to Skilt Gothic Bold Italic or his variant.

Comment: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/172164) lists many resources of maths alphabets and symbols, maybe you'll find a shape you can use there.

Comment: That font is not of LaTeX!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It is available

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tipa}


\begin{document}
\textchi 

\end{document}
```

### EDIT

Another try-could it be `\mathcal{X}`

[image]

Comment: It is not the same, for sure. Observe the top right / bottom left serif, it is curved.

Comment: right you are!!

Comment: @Sigur -- is this correct ?

Comment: I don't think so. Simply compare your image with OP's image. It is much more heavy, thick and rounded. If there is a font producing such glyph in TeX, it would not be in standard way.